# Webclipse Angular IDE template validation unknown attribute

Tags: eclipse, angular

The Webclipse Angular IDE template validation is marking data-toggle as an unknown attribute. I have verified the normal HTML validation within eclipse is configured properly. Where can the Webclipse Angular IDE(https://www.genuitec.com/products/angular-ide/) template validation be configured?

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
```

Comment: What does "verified the normal HTML validation within eclipse is configured properly" mean?

Comment: @nitind Under Window > preferences > web > HTML > validation I have selected ignore specified attribute names in validation data-*, and just to be sure I have set Invalid attribute and Invalid attribute name to ignore. So, I know it is not the standard HTML validator giving the warning, which leaves the Angular IDE template validation as the most likely culprit.